# Laravel Nova - output forms on front end?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am building a system that uses Laravel Nova for managing resources.

There are a couple of instances where I want non-admin users to be able to create resources. The ideal solution would be to define the resource in Nova and embed Nova's own `create` form on the front end of the site.

Has anyone done anything similar, or have any suggestions how to go about this?

Comment: What about giving users access to nova backend and setup Laravel policies to let them access and create only those few resources that you want?

Comment: That's not going to cut it unfortunately - it would be a very odd user journey for people to suddenly find themselves in the Nova backend.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the same endpoints that Nova is using.

For example to get all the fields of a resource:

GET updating fields:
`http://{url}/nova-api/{resource}/{id}/?editing=true&editMode=update`

GET creation fields:
`http://{resource}/nova-api/{resource}/creation-fields?editing=true&editMode=create=`

After the user has filled out the fields, you can use this endpoint to save the new values:

PUT:
`http://{url}/nova-api/{resource}/{id}`